# How to sub string using ruby

Tags: ruby, substring

I'm having below  string value in ruby:

```
response = localhost:8080/test1 and xxx: foopbar,
```

I need output in below format like

```
response = localhost:8080/test1
```

after "and" all string value should be deleted and give only `localhost:8080/test1`. Can someone help how to achieve this in Ruby. thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use gsub regex in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269937/how-to-use-gsub-regex-in-ruby)

Comment: This isn't valid Ruby... it might need some quotes somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a simple regex should do the trick:

```
response = "localhost:8080/test1 and xxx: foopbar"
response.gsub(/ and .+$/,'')  # returns => "localhost:8080/test1"
```

Comment: Use [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) to modify the receiver (i.e. `response`)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying same again here but is not working, I have this string localhost:8080/test1  xxx: foopbar, and I tried to remove xxx and rest of the string using following code but its not working as expected:                response = value.gsub(/ xxx .+$/,'') . Can you tell what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: You rstring contains a colon `:` after the "xxx", so you should change the regular expression to `/ xxx.+$/` (remove the space after the last 'x')