# How to use gsub regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, substring, gsub

I want to remove some part of string from using ruby regex:

value = localhost:8393/foobar/1 test:foobartest
I want to remove "test" from my string [localhost:8393/foobar/1 test:foobartest] and rest of the value so that output should look like:

```
localhost:8393/foobar/1
```

How to do this in ruby? Can you share some sample code to achieve this?

Appreciated your help in advance!
Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, you need to add quotes to the second and fourth lines to make them strings.  The reader can't tell if the first string begins `"value =..."` or `localhost..."`.  Next, what is your criterion for selecting part of the string?  For example, do you want to take everything up to the first whitespace character, or everything up to one or more whitespaces followed by `"test"` or maybe `"test:"`, or  something else? Please correct and clarify by editing your question rather than trying to explain in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Cary! Just I asked how to remove the keyword "test" and rest of the string so I believe it doesn't matter the string should start from value= or localhost....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
value = 'localhost:8393/foobar/1 test:foobartest'

value.split.first
#=> "localhost:8393/foobar/1"
```

Or if you want to use an regexp:

```
value.sub(/ test.*/, '')
"localhost:8393/foobar/1"
```